# Можно ли изменять незагруженные сцены в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю рогалик игру с генерацией новых уровней. Каждый уровень представляется сценой и генерируется при переходе на сцену. Так как генерируется сцена с большим количеством объектов, то боюсь, что при переходе с одного уровня на другой будет задержка. Можно ли как-нибудь генерировать сцену пока персонаж занимается делами на предыдущем уровне и переходить на неё сразу, а не ждать генерации при переходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно грузить сцену [асинхронно](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        // нажать пробел для начала загрузки
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            // запускаем корутину по загрузке сцены в фоне
            StartCoroutine(LoadYourAsyncScene());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene() {
        // приложение грузит сцену в фоне, пока активна другая сцены    
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Scene2");

        // ждём, пока сцена полностью не загрузится
        while (!asyncLoad.isDone) {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```